# Sencha Touch 2.3 TabPanel Position Top Icon / Label Alignment

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Using the tab panel with:
    tabBarPosition: 'top', 
with icons AND title's for the buttons...

**The button / title alignment is:**
**correct**: with Sencha Touch 2.1 CSS
[image: CORRECT 2.1 CSS Image]

**"wrong"**: with 2.2 or 2.3 CSS
[image: WRONG CSS 2.3 IMAGE]

**Question:**
Any ideas what css styling I could use to get icon / text alignment of 2.1 (vertically centered), vs 2.3 (not vertically centered)

I have tried playing with the following, to no avail
 `tabBar:{layout:{align:'center', pack:'center'}}`

[jsFiddle: using sencha touch 2.3 ("Wrong") Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERobishaw/A5r4y/)
[jsFiddle: using 2.1 ("Correct") Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERobishaw/gQuK5/1/)

Comment: For me on Debian, with Chromium v28.0.1500.95 is all perfect.

Comment: you're saying the text is not incorrectly vertically aligned at the TOP in 2.2/2.3 instead of centered?

Comment: If I manually adjust the css of

Comment: If I manually adjust the css of x-button-icon, adding vertical-align: super, I get the desired result...  I wonder though what else this will affect, or if it's the best means to accomplish what I'm looking for....?